# detail page customization with

Tags: visualforce

I have a requirement like this,first i had customised view page,if i click the existing record,detail page will be showed with 4 r 5 fields in this page if i click the button full view it has to show all the fields in the other page in this i also has simplified view button,if i click,it has to show thw fiirst page where it has 4 r 5 fields.i jad customised the vf page like follows.

```
<apex:page standardController="Account" sidebar="false">
  <apex:sectionHeader title="{!$ObjectType.Account.label}" subtitle="{!Account.name}"/>
  <apex:pageBlock title="{!$ObjectType.Account.label} Detail" >
  <apex:pageBlockButtons ><apex:form >
<apex:commandButton action="{!edit}" value="Edit"/>
<apex:commandButton action="{!delete}" value="Delete"/> 
</apex:form> </apex:pageBlockButtons>
<apex:pageBlockSection showHeader="false" columns="2">
<apex:outputField value="{!Account.Name}"/>
<apex:pageBlockSectionItem >
<apex:outputLabel value="Custom Sharing Owner"/>
<apex:outputPanel >
<apex:outputField value="{!Account.OwnerId}"/>&nbsp;
</apex:outputPanel>
</apex:pageBlockSectionItem>
<apex:outputField value="{!Account.Name}"/>
<apex:outputField value="{!Account.Phone}"/>
<apex:outputField value="{!Account.Website}"/>
<apex:pageBlockSectionItem />
   </apex:pageBlockSection>
            <apex:pageBlockSection showHeader="false" columns="2">
<apex:outputField value="{!Account.CreatedById}"/>
<apex:outputField value="{!Account.LastModifiedById}"/>
</apex:pageBlockSection>
        <apex:pageBlockSection showHeader="true" title="Custom Links" columns="3"> 
</apex:pageBlockSection>
  </apex:pageBlock>
</apex:page>
```

pls suggest me how to do,iam a fresher.

Comment: Sahi, this question is too broad for this site. Attempt to meet the requirement yourself (Google and find examples or work through relevant sections of [Trailhead](https://developer.salesforce.com/trailhead/en)) and if you are stuck on a specific part of the solution ask a specific question.

Comment: can u see my detail page customization?!,i had created a page to show customization.

Comment: Sahi, I can now that I've used the {} button to format the Visualforce so it isn't hidden.